# cx_Oracle connection pooling

Tags: cx-oracle

I am from a java background and when I see the java api for connection pooling in oracle, the oracle driver itself provides connection pooling. But in case of `cx_Oracle`, I see only an option to include `threaded=true` or to use `SessionPooling`.

Currently I am going to use threaded - true option. But I am not sure how much of concurrency I can get with this option. Is this truly connection pooling or Is there another way to get this done.

The `cx_Oracle` docs say:

"The threaded argument is expected to be a boolean expression which indicates whether or not Oracle should wrap accesses to **connections** with a mutex. Doing so in single threaded applications imposes a performance penalty of about 10-15% which is why the default is False."

How can we configure `cx_Oracle` to have a connection pool and not a sessionpool. Because both are different in oracle right?

Thanks For your time and advice.

Answer (score 1):

There are some discussion points about when to use connection pooling vs session pooling in the [Oracle OCI doc](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/LNOCI/oci-programming-advanced-topics.htm#LNOCI16653).

For stateless connections (arguably the more common case), use the session pool:

- All the session pool management is handled by OCI.
- Integration with Runtime Load Balancing (RLB) Events for better performance.
- Integration with FAN events and Application Continuity for better availability.
- Integration with DRCP for better scalability.

Comment: @Crhistopher Jones, for us to implement only sessionPool,what requirements must be filled on Oracel DB server side? My DB seems to have DRCP innactive for pooling ...does this means that SessionPool through cx_oracle will have no effect?

Comment: The Session Pool (which is more commonly called a connection pool since it gives the app a pool of connections) is a pool inside cx_Oracle.  DRCP is a pool in the DB.  They can be used independently (but if you use DRCP we recommend also using the Session Pool).  You would use DRCP in some special cases, the common case is where the DB host doesn't have enough memory.  You can definitely use the session pool - and most multi-user apps should use it.

Answer (score 1):

cx_Oracle does not have support for connection pools, only for [session pools](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html#cx_Oracle.SessionPool). The threaded=True option is simply required if you plan to use concurrency in your application and has nothing to do with the use of a session pool. You can get quite reasonable concurrency with this technique, especially if the time required by the database is significantly more than the time required to process the data in Python itself.

As Chris mentioned, you can "roll your own" connection pool as well in Python without too much difficulty, but there are advantages to using the built-in session pooling feature.

Hope that answers your question!